# Rails: style a number_to_currency with HTML <sup> Tag

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Inside a rails app I have this `<%= number_to_currency product.price %>` which gives this html output: $29.98.

Is there a way I can style the above `number_to_currency` html output in order to look like the following?

`<p><sup>$</sup>29<sup>98</sup></p>`

[image]

Comment: I don't know how rails work, but as JS, split output and then wrap it

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Abhishek Pandey... I have no idea how to implement what you just suggested. Can you please provide some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a small example using JS.

```js
let symbol = pricePara.innerText.split("")[0];
let price = pricePara.innerText.split(".");
let priceLHS = price[0].replace(symbol, "");
let priceRHS = price[1];
pricePara.innerHTML = "<sup>" + symbol + "</sup>" + priceLHS + "<sup>" + priceRHS + "</sup>"
```

```css
p{
  font-size:3em;
}
```

```html
<p id="pricePara">$29.98</p>
```

---

With multiple items.

```js
const priceParas = document.querySelectorAll('.price');

priceParas.forEach(function(item) {
  let symbol = item.innerText.split("")[0];
  let price = item.innerText.split(".");
  let priceLHS = price[0].replace(symbol, "");
  let priceRHS = price[1];
  item.innerHTML = "<sup>" + symbol + "</sup>" + priceLHS + "<sup>" + priceRHS + "</sup>"
})
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<p class="price">$29.98</p>
<p class="price">$2934.983</p>
<p class="price">$29434.00398</p>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm looping through an array of products. So when I have only one product, It works fine, but when I have more then one its doesn't show correctly. I think the `id` on the `number_to_currency` is messing everything up.

Comment: Depending on the locale the currency can look totally different: For example, the currency symbol can be more that one character, the symbol could be at the end, the separator could be a comma instead of a dot...

Comment: @spickermann totally agree with you.

Comment: @Dev updated answer, I hope this works

Comment: hmmm... Now it changes all the `<p></p> paragraphs` I have on that page. I have other paragraphs on this page that are not prices

Comment: So if I change to this: `const priceParas = document.querySelectorAll('.price');` and this `<p class="price" ><%= number_to_currency product.price %></p>`. It should work, right?

Comment: yes, it should, It will

Comment: Yes it does... :)))) Thanks @Abhishek Pandey. Edit your answer so I can up-vote and accept it.

Comment: @Dev Edited answer with class